# Adding proxy to a handler - Hapi

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

It is possible to add a proxy object to a pre-handler on Hapi, something like

```
    pre:[{
      assign: 'callProxy'
      method: {
        proxy:{}
      }
    },
    {
      assign: 'getDataFromProxy',
      method: ....
    }
    ]
```

I am trying to use H2O2 but the docs just point to a handler.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the [H2O2 issues log](https://github.com/hapijs/h2o2/issues/5) explicit says:

> Well, it is no longer a proxy... You can just user wreck or request and write your own handler. - hueniverse